# GIT - Deleted all Git projects from my company

Tags: git

I'm a junior member and I haven't worked with git too much. So I downloaded all the projects that I am working and when I made a commit, it was asking me to pull first. It gave some errors so I decided to go to the internet and fix those errors.

So in about 3 hours and end up removing all the commits from the projects and remove some files and merge 3 projects..

**Is there a way to rollback the git to a previous state?** Let's say 6 hours ago?

Comment: Possibly but this very much depends on what you've done in the previous 3 hours... In my experience GIT is very resiliant and generally won't loose stuff unless you really, really screw it up. My advice, time to `fess up and speak to your supervisor before you make this problem any worse

Comment: Some files have <<<HEAD, duplicated code , git urls... all mixed up.

Comment: if you don't have pushed anything and just want to start from the beginning because you don't have a clue what you have done so far. then you could simply clone the project again at start from the beginning.

Comment: that's incredibly vague, seriously, no one on the internet is going to be able to fix this. Speak to you supervisor

Comment: That said if you haven't pushed (have you pushed?) then just delete your local copy and re-pull from the server

Comment: I think i pushed to most of projects because none of them have commits on GitLab.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask to another dev to push its history to the repositories or follow http://ohshitgit.com/

Comment: seriously? some commits schould be there... or the repositorys from projects are brandnew uploaded... Best you ask your supervisor or colleague what to do.